# Is it safe to delete dummy tables Oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

i created a database schema in 11g express edition, however there are some APEX tables and some dummy data...

Is it safe to delete them? also i would like to know what does apex means and why they have a dollar sign, thanks...

```
APEX$_ACL                      TABLE
APEX$_WS_FILES                 TABLE
APEX$_WS_HISTORY               TABLE
APEX$_WS_LINKS                 TABLE
APEX$_WS_NOTES                 TABLE
APEX$_WS_ROWS                  TABLE
APEX$_WS_TAGS                  TABLE
APEX$_WS_WEBPG_SECTIONS        TABLE
APEX$_WS_WEBPG_SECTION_HISTORY TABLE
```

[image: apex cmd]

[image: apex web]

I used SYS to create a new user, the new user was created along with a workspace and a database schema, please see the images above.

Comment: Dollar sign usually means "don't touch me".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest removing those tables, no.  The Oracle XE browser-based interface is written in APEX (Application Express, a framework for developing web-based apps in the Oracle database).  If you break APEX, that interface will likely stop working.

Answer (score 6):

APEX is an acronym for Oracle Application Express.  Those tables are there to support some of the tools within APEX (like Websheets), so you should leave those alone.

Answer (score 4):

Talking about the APEX$_ tables: Given that you are **not using any Websheets applications**, it's safe to drop them. This won't bother any of your regular APEX database applications.

What if you change your mind later on? Creating your first Websheet application, the wizard will detect all missing tables (even corrupt tables if you happended to alter them). A dialog comes up telling you "The database objects required to create Websheet applications are either invalid or do not exist". Click on "Manage Websheets Database Objects" and easily recover them in another wizard within just a few seconds. And you're done.

Test this behaviour in a free evaluation workspace on apex.oracle.com.